# Where can I find tables of Snarks?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a conjecture that pertains to [snarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)). I would like to test an algorithm I have developed, but I have not been able to find a list of snarks.

Do you know a good graph database (like a bunch of JSON objects which describe various graphs) which would be a good source of snarks?

*Edit:* I would like to find a freely available one. I found that Sage's Common Graph module has 6 snarks.

Comment: If anyone is curious: "In the mathematical field of graph theory, a snark is a connected, bridgeless cubic graph with chromatic index equal to 4."

Comment: Mathematica's GraphData[] has a lot of snarks.

Comment: On arXiv: ["Generation and Properties of Snarks"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6690). The abstract mentions a list of all snarks up to 36 vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

House of graphs hosts a list of all snarks on up to 34 vertices and some other snarks of higher girth. See [here](https://hog.grinvin.org/Snarks).

If you would like to use that within Sage, you download the file with the respective snark and (say it is saved under the name snarks.txt) you do

```
for line in open('snarks.txt'):
    G = Graph(line)
    testmything(G)
```

Comment: House of Graphs has recently moved. The updated link is https://houseofgraphs.org/meta-directory/snarks